# How can I disable auto updating PlayFramework Activator commands when create project?

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, offline

When I want to use activator command for create project for each command it try update itself for example

when write (in CMD)

- sbt (update all libraries of SBT)
- activator (update all libraries of Play)
- activator new my-first-app play-java (update latest template)
- eclipse  (create eclipse project needs new libraries too !!!)

I want to create my project with current and offline libraries (I want to work with latest offline distribution only)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Resolver can help you in this situation

resolvers += (
    "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
)

please refer this link

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies

Answer (score 1):

To disable check update while you create a new project on Play framework, you can use these parameters like below:

```
 activator -Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false -Dactivator.checkForTemplateUpdates=false new
```

To be offline permanently:
1- If you installed SBT, add these parameters in `.../conf/sbtconfig.txt`

```
-Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false
-Dactivator.checkForTemplateUpdates=false
```

2- If you didn't install SBT you can add parameters to `%UserProfile%\.activator\activatorconfig.txt` or `%UserProfile%\.activator\%APP_VERSION%\activatorconfig.txt`